# Restrict access to different site sections by ip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wildcard, ip-restrictions

In our MVC 3 solution we have a site with many sections. Customer want to have a possibility to manage access to each section by IP address(from admin part). What are the standard ways of implementing this requirements?
I see, smth like this: every section has a list of wildcards, that represent IP addresses, and then we we somehow validate IP address using this wildcards.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. What do you have so far? What worked? What didn't? (How do you deal with changing IP addresses? With NAT? With IPv6?)

Comment: I didn't try anything yet, because I thought this tas kis pretty standard and there must be standard solutions. Regarding IPv6 - yes, it would be perfect if I could validate IPv^ addresses

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest not using directly IP addresses in your code - these tend to change from time to time. Do create system of "zones", similar like in many personal firewalls.

My solution would be basically like this :

Create custom authorization attribute

```
public class AuthorizeZone: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string _zone; 
    public AuthorizeZone(string zoneName)
    {
        _zone = zoneName;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var zone = GetZoneIpMappingsFromXMLorDB_IdeallyCached(_zone);
        return zone.ContainsIp(httpContext.Request.UserHostAddress); // implement by simple list or ip-mask
    }        
}
```

you then use it like this

```
[AuthorizeZone("Intranet")]
public ActionResult Foo()
{}
```

Your zones definitions is up to you, use XML, database, whatever...

Comment: thank you for suggestion. but it doesn't cover my needs. the things I need: some easy and flexible way of editing ID list by not-it-specialists and a way to check this permissions. But anyway, I will use your idea

Comment: my solution will certainly satisfy your needs - once you have "zones" in database, you can make some user-friendly administration to edit them